# Power stage for driving a 100W piezo in resonance

Tags: power-electronics, resonance, piezo

I'm trying to design a power stage for driving a piezo transducer. It has resonance at about 1 MHz. My system has a DC voltage of 24V. The circuit will be locking frequency based on phase of voltage and current. The power delivered to piezo should be maximum of 100W, and maximal voltage should be in order of 100Vrms.

I'm struggle with design of power stage. What is the optimal solution?

I thought about using half-bridge forward configuration with step-up transformer (with output LC tank for getting fundamental frequency), but with coupling coefficient about 0.95 it needs to have <1uH of primary inductance to transfer 100W. That will be quite hard to achieve in real transformer.

About control delivered power, I plan to use adjustable step-down converter that supply voltage to half bridge - using PWM on half bridge MOSFETs working at such high frequency could be challenging.

How do I do it properly?

Edit:

- By optimal I mean simple robust and cheap solution.
- The frequency will be precisely controlled with resolution on order of 100Hz in range of 0.9-1.1MHz (direct digital synthesis.)

Comment: What about using a DC/DC boost converter and a class C GAN FET output stage, that drives the L/C tank?

Comment: Optimal in what sense? -- Please add requirements for efficiency, overall size, power dissipation, operating temperature, parts cost, etc. || You mention control concerns: what range of power is required, what range of load conditions (is the transducer constant, or will a range of parts be connected; what will they be loaded by; etc.), how often does it need to change, and how precisely (control bandwidth and noise); how stable does the frequency need to be (could frequency-shift control be viable?), etc.